# comparison of infinispan and Jboss cache

Tags: caching, jboss, infinispan

I am not native and am poor at English. Please understand the situation.

I have been carrying out a comparison of Infinispan and JBoss Cache.
Both products are open-source. The JBoss Cache website has at the top the statement *'Project In Maintenance Mode'*. Growth of the product will not be carried
out, but it is recognized they will carry out stability based changes.

Moreover, I recognize Infinispan being a successor of kind to JBoss
Cache.

However, the point that Infinispan is better than JBoss Cache in regard to performance or
stability is unknown to me. Since it is unclear to me after an investigation from the web site,
may I have it taught?

Answer (score 4):

As one of the Infinispan developers, and old JBoss Cache contributor, I'd suggest you have a read to the [FAQS](https://docs.jboss.org/author/x/QgY5).

They explain all you need to know about the relationship between Infinispan and JBoss Cache. The point is, unless you're tied to old JBoss Cache, you should be using Infinispan.

Answer (score 1):

On stability point of view, Red Hat have producterize Infinispan into Data Grid providing enterprise support of the product, so they think they have correct stability.

On performance, I found some local cache scenario (Infinispan is customizable enough to be not distributed) coparaison with JBoss Cache and eChache http://infinispan.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/infinispan-as-local-cache.html

Feature wise Infinispan is more complete.

Even with these argument, actual use, ease of use and performance, depending of team experience, actual caching scenario, foreseeable future scenario can be guest.  You probably need to make some prototype to prove the fit.  (But I will start with Infinispan...)

Answer (score 0):

I would start with infinispan too. Currently I am using Infinispan 5.1.5 in pre-production env. I have never used JBoss Cache.
Infinispan 5.1.5 is used in RedHat JDG and you could buy support if needed.